# How to mock HttpPostedFileBase using moq in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

My controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTeam(Team model, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          if (upload != null)
          {
              // Get the file
              string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
              // Save the file in file сохраняем файл в папку Files в проекте
              upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/" + fileName));
          }
         teamRepository.CreatTeam(model);

         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Player");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

My unit test method without upload image:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanCreateTeam()
{
        //Arrange
        Mock<ITeamRepository> teamsMock = new Mock<ITeamRepository>();
        Team newTeam = new Team()
        {
            Id = 0,
            Name = "Chicago Bulls",
            Path = "CHI.jpg",
        };
        TeamController controller = new TeamController(teamsMock.Object);
        //Action
        ActionResult result = controller.CreateTeam(newTeam);
        teamsMock.Verify(m => m.CreatTeam(newTeam));
        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
}
```

I don't have idea how make the right unit test for this action. However the action are working right without any problem.

How in this test method add the functional for test of `HttpPostedFileBase` which upload the image?

Comment: what you have there is not a unit test. you've just created something brittle which is tied to the MVC framework itself. the "test" has deep knowledge about how your code works, meaning that any change in the code will trigger a test failure and the test itself will need to change in order to match the new code. That is the very definition of a brittle test. the more of those you add, the worse it gets.

Comment: @remk93, Have you checked my updated answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First update your `CreateTeam` POST method as follows because there is a problem in `upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/" + fileName));` line.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTeam(Team model, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          if (upload != null)
          {
              // Get the file
              string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
              var fileUploadPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"),fileName);
              upload.SaveAs(fileUploadPath);
          }
         teamRepository.CreatTeam(model);

         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Player");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Then write your test method as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanCreateTeam()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<ITeamRepository> teamRepositoryMock = new Mock<ITeamRepository>();
    Team newTeam = new Team()
    {
        Id = 0,
        Name = "Chicago Bulls",
        Path = "CHI.jpg",
    };


    var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var serverMock = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    serverMock.Setup(x => x.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/")).Returns(@"c:\work\app_data");
    httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Server).Returns(serverMock.Object);

    var fileMock = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    fileMock.Setup(x => x.FileName).Returns("file1.pdf");

    TeamController controller = new TeamController(teamRepositoryMock.Object);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContextMock.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

    //Act
    ActionResult result = controller.CreateTeam(newTeam , fileMock.Object);

    //Assert
    fileMock.Verify(x => x.SaveAs(@"c:\work\app_data\file1.pdf"));
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));
}
```

I have checked the above code in a test project and it works perfectly.

Comment: i took the NullReferenceException , StackTrace:

to this part of co

`upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/" + fileName));`


and this 

`ActionResult result = controller.CreateTeam(newTeam, mockedImageFile);`

Comment: You have to mock upload.SaveAs() method too.

Comment: I add in test but anyway the same problem
`mockedImageFile.SaveAs(controller.Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/" + mockedImageFile.FileName));`

Comment: test was failed

Comment: Okay! no problem! I shall try my in my side. May be I shall update the answer later.

Comment: Okay! give me remote access! I am solving your issue.

Comment: https://github.com/remk93/Project-to-final-task that's my project. 
Controller Team , action CreateTeam, in WebUI project
and TeamTests.cs in UnitTests project

Comment: @remk93 Please check my updated answer. I have tested the updated answer in ta test project and it works perfectly. Hope this will solve your problem now.

Comment: for my bad i took
`Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.SaveAs("c:\work\file.pdf")
No setups configured.`
try to some options didn't help

Comment: You did not copy my code correctly! I see you wrote `x => x.SaveAs("c:\work\file.pdf")` but it actually `c:\work\app_data\file1.pdf` . it should be `fileMock.Verify(x => x.SaveAs(@"c:\work\app_data\file1.pdf"));`

Comment: i have checked your case first of all, but the same problem, after that i have made experiment with other case , the same problem
`Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.SaveAs("c:\work\app_data\file1.pdf")`

Comment: Please give remote access with team viewer.

Comment: Please copy the my my code for both `CreateTeam` and `CanCreateTeam` without changing single line of code.